# AI function infinite loop/not working

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, python-2.x

Still working on Connect 4 and I'm having issues with the AI. I've been using functions that are identical to the ones used for victory checking, and yet I'm getting infinite loops or that the code simply isn't working.

Here's the function

```
def AIhor(array):
global blockwin
for x in range(0, 6):
    x = array[x]
    for y in range(1, 5):
        if x[y] in ("@", "#"):
            if ((x[y] == x[y + 1]) and x[y] == x[y + 2]) and (x[y + 3] == "O"):
                return True
                blockwin = y + 3
                break
            elif ((x[y] == x[y + 1]) and (x[y] == x[y + 3]) and (x[y + 2] == "O")):
                return True
                blockwin = y + 2
                break
            elif ((x[y] == x[y + 2]) and (x[y] == x[y + 3]) and (x[y + 2] == "O")):
                return True
                blockwin = y + 1
                break
            elif ((x[y + 1] == x[y + 2]) and (x[y + 1] == x[y + 3]) and (x[y] == "O")):
                return True
                blockwin = y
                break
            else:
                if (x == 5 and y == 4):
                    return False
                    break
```

and here's the function call:

```
g = ['A', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
h = ['B', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
i = ['C', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
j = ['D', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
k = ['E', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
l = ['F', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
m = [' ', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']
a = g
b = h
c = i
d = j
e = k
f = l
n = m
afortests = [a, b, c, d, e, f]

if AIhor(afortests):
    player2choice = blockwin
else:
    player2choice = random.randint(1, 7)
```

Comment: Please, indent your code properly and bear with us, who do not know, what you mean by "Connect 4" and "AI" and explain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Code isn't working" is *not* a useful error report. What's happening that shouldn't, or what isn't that should?

But I can tell you right away that you have a large number of lines of code that will never be executed. In each `if` statement you have a `return` followed by some other code. But that other code will never be executed, as the return does exactly what it says and returns straight away. The code after it in the same block simply won't ever be reached, and `blockwin` will not be modified.

Comment: What I meant by "not working" is that the opponent doesn't block the third open slot in the Connect 4 game. So if I use return, does that mean that "break" statement is unnecessary?

Comment: But they do different things, especially as you have a nested loop. `break` will break out of the current loop, but continue the top-level one. `return` will return completely, breaking out of all code in the function, including the top-level loop.